# How do I get a list of methods supported by a COM object

Tags: c#, com

I have a C++ COM server application that I'm calling from my managed C# app. The COM server changes from time to time as new COM methods are added.

In my managed application, I create the object as follows:

```
Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(...));
Object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
```

I would like to know if the COM object implements a specific method. I believe that I need to call GetMethod() on the comType as follows:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = comType.GetMethods();
```

However, this appears to return a list of methods of the .Net 'Type' object and not the COM server app. I may be missing a cast but I'm not sure what I need to cast it to.

```
((???)comType).GetMethods();
```

Comment: Aye! Aye!! Captain @Kirk!

Comment: Are you looking for runtime evaluation of available functionality?  I see reflection tidbits in your question.  Seems odd to have runtime checks on COM interop functionality.  Design time - you can view the object browser...

Comment: There are several versions of the COM application server. From one version to another there may have been new COM methods added. I thought this was a way to determine if the particular version a customer was running supported a specific method. C# includes the GetMethods() method so I assumed that I could call it at runtime.